# Extracting numbers from a string without the following characters in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have street addresses like the following:

```
123 Street Ave
1234 Road St Apt B
12345 Passage Way
```

Now, I'm having a hard time extracting just the street numbers without any of the street names.

I just want:

```
123
1234
12345
```

Comment: Read the docs about regular expressions - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1003

Comment: Show us the query you came up with, it isn't too hard to attempt for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, two simple options return the desired result. One uses regular expressions (selects the first number in a string), while another one returns the first substring (which is delimited by a space).

```
SQL> with test (address) as
  2    (select '123 Street Ave' from dual union all
  3     select '1234 Road St Apt B' from dual union all
  4     select '12345 Passage Way' from dual
  5   )
  6  select
  7    address,
  8    regexp_substr(address, '^\d+') result_1,
  9    substr(address, 1, instr(address, ' ') - 1)  result_2
 10  from test;

ADDRESS            RESULT_1           RESULT_2
------------------ ------------------ ------------------
123 Street Ave     123                123
1234 Road St Apt B 1234               1234
12345 Passage Way  12345              12345

SQL>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. How does the sequence know to extract from the first blank space and not the second, for example? Can you have multiple blank spaces in the above sequence? So like ...INSTR(address, ' ', ' ')?

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to select something else, edit your question and post examples of what you have and what you'd want to get; me (or someone else) will try to answer. As of your question: how does it know what to extract? You'd use different parameters for those functions, or - perhaps - completely different functions, or you'd even write your own - there are numerous possibilities.